# First Normal Form - Exact one value rule

Tags: sql, oracle

According to the first normal form, every row and column intersection contains exactly one value from the applicable domain.

If name is divided into three part First Name, Middle Name , Last Name.
For few value if I gave middle name as Null.

Does it violate the 1NF rule?

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````  
Client_ID    |   First Name  | Middle_Name |  Last_Name 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
3256         |   Jamie       | NULL        |  Zacharias
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
8524         |   Madonna     | Doremus     |  NULL
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: No, it doesn't violate the 1NF rule. Codd considered `NULL`s to be values.

Comment: `null` is a value per-se, meaning the absence of value, I wouldn't say this violates 1NF

Comment: I'm agree with @David Feber => this [Link](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/25955/first-normal-form-1nf) : `no row/column intersections contain a null value`

Comment: I suggest except three fields you use two fields.

Comment: Of course it violates 1NF, because NULLS are NOT values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not violate the 1st normal form. A violation of the first normal form would have more than one value for a column within the same row. Using your example, if someone changed their last name and you simply added a new distinct value to the same row, or you tossed in nicknames to the first name column like:
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

### Client_ID    |   First Name  | Middle_Name |  Last_Name

3256         |   Jamie, James| NULL        |  Zacharias
                                              Huffington

---

8524         |   Madonna     | Doremus     |  NULL

For more information, see this Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Answer (score 0):

No, the first normal form doesn't say you shouldn't have occasional `NULL` values in your column. You would be violating the first normal form if you would put the whole name in one column (let's say in an array column) and still treat the firstname and lastname as separate entities, like this:

```
Client_ID    |   Name                   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
3256         |   Jamie, NULL, Zacharias |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
8524         |   Madonna, Doremus, NULL |
```

The applicable domain is `names` with values like `Jamie, Zacharias, Madonna` and `Doremus`. In my example you have now `Jamie` and `Zacharias` on the first row which means more than one value from the given domain in one column.

Comment: 'Name' is being a composite attribute(it is better to keep the original way of dividing it into fistname, lastname, middlename) does not seems a good database design.

Comment: Well, as I said in my answer the example I gave **would violate** the 1st normal form (while the current setup in the question doesn't). I wanted to give an example on how you shouldn't do it...

Answer (score 0):

E.F. Codd's definition of first normal form (1NF) was very simple:

> A relation [table] is in first normal form if it has the property that none of its domains [sets of possible values] has elements [values] which are themselves sets.

Under this definition it is obvious that first normal form does not preclude having `NULL` values since a `NULL` isn't a set. In addition, Codd's Rule 3 requires that an RDBMS treat `NULL` values systematically.

Now, C.J. Date defines first normal form differently and excludes `NULL`s. That is, any table with one or more nullable columns does not meet Date's definition.

Personally, even though `NULL`s can be annoying at times, they do have a place in RDBMSs and I'll go with Codd's definition over Date's.

Answer (score 0):

This seems fine according to 1NF, it seems your primary key does not repeat for nay of the entries. You would violate 1NF if you consider the firstName, MiddleName and/or LastName as a primary key(Which is not advisable). As of now this seems good.

If you do have

**1, repeating group**(example take a look the last two rows with the same primary keys)

```
   Client_ID    |   Name                   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
3256         |   Jamie, NULL, Zacharias |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
8524         |   Madonna, Null, NULL |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
8524         |   Thomas, Doremus, NULL |
```

**2, You do not have primary key**

**3, if not all of you attributes are directly(Partial dependency) or indirectly(transitive dependency) are dependent on the primary key**

*Then in any of these three cases your table violates 1NF*